# Mozart IDE (emacs) parse error

Tags: emacs, parse-error, oz, mozart

Wrote this code using the mozart emacs system I downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mozart-oz/files/latest/download):

This is my code:

```
declare fun {Mult X Y}
      X*Y end
end
{Browse {Mult 1 1}}
```

When I run it it says:

> parse error in file Oz, line 6, column 1.

What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please refrain from links that initiate file downloads.

Answer (score 1):

My Mozart Emacs gives a much better error message.

> %*************************** parse error ************************
>
> %**
>
> %** syntax error, unexpected T_end, expecting T_ENDOFFILE
>
> %**
>
> %** in file "Oz", line 3, column 0
>
> %** ------------------ rejected (1 error)

I says that you have a superfluous "end". "declare" does not need "end".